# Collpasing Toolbar not Working (Parallax)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've implemented a RecyclerView with multiple layouts.
And I followed some tutorial about collapsing ToolbarLayout.

But it doesn't work for me..
I wonder why.

Here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bsu"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPOI"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="ProgressBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primaryColorLight</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
    <style name="MenuTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primaryColorLight</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Been stuck on this parallax ToolBar for too long.
Hope someone here can help me.

Comment: have you looked at the SupportDesignDemos: toolbar parallax sample on GitHub? https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/SupportDesignDemos/res/layout/design_appbar_toolbar_parallax_overlap.xml

Comment: yes. Thats almost the same as mine

Comment: Help. still stuck on this. :'(

Answer (score 0):

```
app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.6"
```

Try adding that line for the image just below

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bsu"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.6" />
```

You can play around with the value and see how it affects the parallax.

Comment: In the code i used i only had android:fitsSystemWindows="true" for the co ordinator layout.So maybe you could try removing that line from all the places except the co ordinator layout and then give it a try.

Comment: still not working. Maybe my theme has affect the coordinator layout or something?